# Hibernate one-to-one relationship seems to require bi-directionality only when using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been learning about hibernate the last few days and had some general question. I started learning how to map the relationships in my project using xml mapping; now I am trying to go back through my project and see if I can implement annotations. I seem to keep running into the same question, in order for an aggregated relationship to get mapped properly I keep having to make an instance of the classes I aggregated from in the classes I am aggregating to, lol, that seems so weird… Putting an instance of the class, you aggregated from, into the class you aggregated to… Is that like an infinite loop? Like yesterday, I was trying to build this xml mapping, with annotation.

Class user...

```
private int userId--
private string username--
private string password--
Private Person person--
```

Class person...

```
private int personId;--
private String firstName;--
private String lastName;--
private String email;--
```

Mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping package="my.bank.BLL.objects">
<class name="User" table="USER" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="userId" type="int" column="USER_ID">
        <generator class="native"/> 
    </id>
    <property name="username" type="string"> 
        <column name="USERNAME" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string"> 
        <column name="PASSWORD" length="45" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="person" class="my.bank.BLL.objects.Person"
                cascade="save-update" lazy="false">
    </one-to-one>
</class>
```

And this worked perfectly, I did not have to reference anything special in my persons xml mapping, just map the columns. Well.. I did have to make sure the personId matched the UserID, but that wasn't hard.

And yesterday I couldn't believe how much I struggled just to get annotations to do this same thing...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private int userId;

@Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String username;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String password;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
```

And the person class...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
private int personId;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String email;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;   <------------------------------
```

With the annotation is when I have to start referencing my aggregated object inside the object I aggregated from, which confuses me.

Comment: So what happens when you don't include a reference to User from Person?  Exception?  Stacktrace?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user0_.person_PERSON_ID' in 'field list'

Comment: Tip: annotate your fields and not your methods. Less code to paste on SO questions for a start.

Comment: Don't have time to investigate thoroughly however may be because of the different ID properties on User and Person. See the following and think about whether you have to specify the referencedColumnName.

Comment: What does your database schema look like?  How are you connecting the two tables?  Is this a legacy table, or do you have the ability to change it to meet your needs?

Comment: Its a schema I made up. For these two tables it is just a user with a primary key, and a person with a primary key and a foreign key to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I suspect the problem is that your `USER_ID` foreign key column is in the `PERSON` table.  This means you need annotations on the person side (and hence, a `user` field) in order to configure the Person-User relationship.  If you had a `PERSON_ID` column in the `USER` table instead, then I think you could do this in the `User` class:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
```

Again, I would have to set all of this up to see if that is the case or not, but it is something to try.